# Custom markup with preg_replace only limiting to 1

Tags: php, function, preg-replace

**PHP function:**

```
function b($text) {    
  $body="<b>$text</b>";
  return $body; 
}
```

**Preg_Replace:**

```
function replaceTags($body) {    
  $body = preg_replace('!\[b](.*?)\[\/b\]!Uei', "''.b('$1','$2').''", $body, -1);    
  return $body; 
}
```

The code works... to a certain extent. It apparently only limits to the first instance every time. I accidentally broke this when I was copying code, inserted it within each other and it displayed the inner tags in bold.

**Example:**

```
*Code:* [b]This is Hi.[/b] Hello world. [b]This is Hi2.[/b]    
*Output:* **This is Hi.[/b] Hello world. [b]This is Hi2.**
```

I'm new to using **preg_replace**. I'm thinking the pattern is slightly off or possibly missing something. Which is why it displays the first instance only. I've also tried this with a MySQL query and that is limited to one row as well.

I'm trying to utilize a simplistic markup for the user end, but I would like to use MySQL queries as a custom tag (again, works, but only displays first record) if need be.

Thanks. Any help or advice is much appreciated.

Comment: Indent 4 spaces or highlight and ctl-k to format as a code block, so the HTML tags don't get eaten :)

Comment: Ah thanks. I'm a n00b to asking questions on here. I always use it as a resource for having answers. I will keep a note of that. Thanks. [=

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the `U` pattern modifier from your regular expression. It `inverts` the meaning of the lazy operator and makes it to be `greedy`. If you want to support `UTF-8`, use `u` (lower case)

```
$body = preg_replace('!\[b\](.*?)\[\/b\]!uei', "''.b('$1','$2').''", $body, -1);
```

Comment: Fantastic! works like a charm now. I knew it was something that I was looking over. Thanks a lot! You're awesome.